# Can't connect to Mongodb using Bun V1.0.6 and Nextjs v13

Tags: linux, mongodb, next.js, backend, bun

```
  ⚠ /api error - [project]/node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/mongocryptd_manager.js - Error resolving commonjs request
unable to resolve dynamic

 error - node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/mongocryptd_manager.js:37:23  Error resolving commonjs request

  35 |         // Spawned with stdio: ignore and detached: true
  36 |         // to ensure child can outlive parent.
> 37 |         this._child = spawn(cmdName, this.spawnArgs, {
     |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 38 |             stdio: 'ignore',
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 39 |             detached: true
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 40 |         });
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  41 |         this._child.on('error', () => {
  42 |             // From the FLE spec:
  43 |             // "The stdout and stderr of the spawned process MUST not be exposed in the driver
unable to resolve dynamic
It was not possible to find the requested file.
    Parsed request as written in source code: dynamic
    Path where resolving has started: [project]/node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/mongocryptd_manager.js
    Type of request: commonjs request
    Import map: No import map entry
```

I recently got this error while I was testing mongodb with bun V1.0.6 for a side project. My code is :

```
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from "mongodb";

const client = new MongoClient(
  `${process.env.MONGODB_URI}`
  // , {
  //   serverApi: {
  //     version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
  //     strict: true,
  //     deprecationErrors: true,
  //   },
  //}
);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    await client.db(`${process.env.MONGODB_DB}`).command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log(
      "Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!"
    );
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
// run().catch(console.dir);

export { run };
This is the Nextjs backend-in-frontend code that I use to verify if db is alive or not:
```

This is my nextjs backend code that I use to verify if the db is alive:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { run } from "./db/ping";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  if (req.body) {
    const { username, password } = await new Response(req.body).json();
    await run(); ///check if db alive.
    if (username === "1234" && password === "1234") {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { success: true, message: "Login successful" },
        { status: 200 }
      );
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { success: false, message: "Invalid credentials" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I followed the example that is on their blog [website](https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v0.5.2)  and I got the error above.
Any ideas about how to fix that?